# data from Barcode Scanner directly into a cell in Jtable

Tags: java, barcode-scanner

How can I write a java code, that it reads data frome barcode-scanner from USB device and shows in a selected cell in Jtable? Should I access on USB Port?

Comment: seems like spoon-feeding to me. better you post some code or at least a approach otherwise your question will be taken down of SO.

Comment: Ok, then, you don't know its answer :)

Comment: Indeed. I don't know but i do know few policies of OS. that's why i'm asking you to change you question approach if you don't want it to be removed eventually. I may not flag it to remove but not sure about the others.